# Let AWS SQS run a php script via AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I want to send a message to a queue using the AWS SDK. The instances of my worker environment should accept and execute the message. Problem here is that I don't know how to pass the command to run a particular php script.

```
 $params = [
    'MessageAttributes' => [
        "name" => [
            "DataType" => "String",
            "StringValue" => "test"
        ],
        "url" => [
            "DataType" => "String",
            "StringValue" => "/jobs/send_test_email.php"
        ],
    ],
    'MessageBody' => "Test",
    'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl
];
```

I think I have to pass the command via the MessageAttribute, but I can't find any other examples than "Hello World"

Comment: -1

PHP code examples for SQS can be found in the AWS Github repo located here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/php/example_code/sqs

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me. There must be a list of the parameters MessageAttributer expects. Someting like targetURL.

Comment: Look at the PHP REF docs here -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sqs-2012-11-05.html#sendmessage

Comment: I was already on this page. But to what extent should that help me? How does it help me if I name an attribute Title or Author

Comment: What "command" are you talking about?  SQS is a pipe - you put things in and get things out.  It doesn't execute anything per se.  What reads the pipe (for example, an AWS Lambda) can execute things.  Or you could have a PHP server that is reading from the pipe and interpreting the headers - that is code you have to write.  To send a message you can use [the example send code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-sqs-SendMessage.php.html).  To receive you use [the example receive code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-sqs-SendMessage.php.html).

Comment: By "command" I meant message. For example, if I set up a cron job for a worker environment, I also specify a URL. Like: 
`version: 1
cron:
  - name: "shipping"
    url: "/jobs/send_test_email.php"
    schedule: "36 14 * * *"`

But I don't know how to specify the same with AWS SDK without a schedule